# Why Google sheets missing the last email when sending emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

my google sheet will email a PDF copy of the sheet to a list of 4 emails ( in cells L5:L8 )
but it seems that the email in cell L8 never picked , logger shows it in the array ! .
see my code and help figuring the problem !? I'm suspecting something wrong in my FOREACH loop .

```
    function onEdit2(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange('L11').getValue();
  if (r == "Send") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ssID = ss.getId();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetName = ss.getName();
    var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var setcolor= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setTabColor("#0000A0");
   var emails= sheet.getRange("L5:L8").getValues();


    var subject = "Daily report ";
    var body = "Please find the attached" +" "+ key ;

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" 
      + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + 
      "&exportFormat=pdf";


    var tempSheet = ss.insertSheet("tempSheet"); // Added
    sheet.getRange("A1:J27").copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1, 1)); // Added
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
    var sheetgId = tempSheet.getSheetId(); // Added

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token}});
    var contents = result.getContent();
    emails.forEach(function(email){

    MailApp.sendEmail(email.toString(),sheetName ,body, {attachments: [{fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content: contents, mimeType: "application//pdf"}]});

    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet); // Added
  })
  }
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for ( var i = 0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet1 = sheets[i];
     sheet1.getRangeList(['L3','L11']).clearContent();
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you add another email address to L9 and change your emails range to `L5:L9`? Will L8's email work, and L9 fail? Also, are you using different email addresses for your tests or are they all the same?

Comment: I tried changing the range to L9 and it didn't work ! , its weird because the values are stored in emails are all of cell from L5:L8 ( shown in logger ), yes I have a different email in each cell .

Comment: If you switch the last email address (in L8) with the first email address (in L5), do the same email addresses not receive an email? or is it now switched? (I'm just trying to determine if the last email address is for some reason marking this email as spam).

Comment: I thought about it and whatever email in L8 & L9 wont go through :\ .I'm starting to believe the mailapp doesn't allow more than 3 recipients

Comment: [It's definitely allowed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). I have one script that sends out a five every time someone fills out a form. Maybe all of your testing has hit the daily limit?

Comment: Was it your intentions to delete this sheet four times? `emails.forEach(function(email){
 MailApp.sendEmail(email.toString(),sheetName ,body, {attachments: [{fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content: contents, mimeType: "application//pdf"}]});
ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet); // Added
  })` also attachments should be an array of files not file names.

Comment: Could you try maybe changing the ```forEach()``` function to a **for loop** to verify the issue is not the ```forEach()``` thing?

Comment: Please consider the suggested recommendations and append the Latest version of your code to your question